# Loading image (opencv /c++)

Tags: c++

I want to load an image that might not exist, because it come from another processing.

```
image = cvLoadImage("test.jpg", 1);
```

What is the best approach to try loading it until the image come ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path doesn't exist until a certain time, you can check if it was loaded or empty:

```
Mat imageIwantToLoad;
while (imageIwantToLoad.empty()) {
    imageIwantToLoad = imread("test.jpg", 1);
}
cout << endl << "My image was finally loaded!";
```

But you should implement other way to know or wait until the file is ready.

Comment: done !! sorry I'm new in stackoverflow and this was my first question ;)